# »sieht aus, dass« oder »sieht aus, als ob«?

Tags: subjunctive

Wieder regt mich das Buch *Denksport Deutsch* von Daniel Scholten zu einer Frage an. In einem sehr ausführlichen und interessanten Kapitel seines Buches widmet er sich dem Konjunktiv. Er stellt darin sehr gewagte, aber durchaus plausible und nachvollziehbare Thesen auf, die der traditionellen Grammatik ganz grundlegend widersprechen. Und solange es sich um Grammatik im Sinn von *»Analysieren von bereits produzierter Sprache, und Benennen der Bestandteile und ihrer Beziehungen untereinander«* geht, bin ich durchaus geneigt, seinen Thesen ein Stück weit zu folgen, ganz einfach, weil sie, zumindest in den angeführten Beispielen, mehr Sinn ergeben als die herkömmliche Grammatik. (Zum Verifizieren mit Hilfe von Texten aus dem wirklichen Leben bin ich noch nicht gekommen.)

Aber wenn Scholten dann hergeht, und aus seinen Thesen ableitet, dass gewisse Formulierungen, die durchaus gängig sind, falsch wären, und sie durch andere Formulierungen ersetzt haben will, dann fällt es mir schwer, auch diesen Schritt zu gehen.

Als Beispiel greift Scholten diesen Satz heraus:

> 1. Der Kommissar sah aus, **als ob** er ein Nickerchen vertragen **könnte.**
>      <sub>(Seite 239)</sub>

Scholten behauptet, dieser Satz sei falsch. Richtig sei stattdessen dieser Satz:

> 2. Der Kommissar sah ganz danach aus, **dass** er ein Nickerchen vertragen **konnte.**
>      <sub>(Seite 240)</sub>

Die wesentlichen Unterschiede:

- »als ob« → »dass«
- »könnte« (Konjunktiv II, oder *»Irrealis«* in Scholtens Diktion) → »konnte« (Indikativ)

Laut Scholten drückt die Konstruktion *», als (ob) + Konjuktiv II«* einen Vergleich mit etwas aus, dass nicht der Fall (also irreal) ist. Ein korrektes Beispiel ist laut Scholten:

> 3. Der Kommissar benahm sich mal wieder, **als wäre** jeder verdächtig.
>      <sub>(Seite 238)</sub>

In Wahrheit ist nicht jeder verdächtig, daher beschreibt der Relativsatz etwas Irreales, und das Verhalten des Kommissars wird mit dieser irrealen Situation verglichen.

Im Satz (1) beschreibt der Relativsatz aber einen tatsächlich vorliegenden Zustand, also keineswegs etwas Irreales. Und das sei der Grund, die Verwendung des Konjunktiv II hier als falsch anzusehen. Weiters liege kein Vergleich vor, sondern es werde etwas inhaltliches ausgesagt. Daher müsse man einen *»Inhaltssatz«* verwenden, und Inhaltssätze werden - im Gegensatz zu Vergleichssätzen - nicht mit *»als (ob)«* eingeleitet, sondern mit *»dass«*.

Mein persönliches Sprachgefühl steht hier im Widerspruch zu Scholtens Behauptungen. Ich halte den Satz (1) (*etwas sieht aus, also ob etwas wäre*) für völlig korrekt, aber Satz (2) (*etwas sieht aus, dass etwas ist*) erscheint mir falsch.

**Meine Fragen:**

1. Wer hat recht? Scholten oder ich?
2. Ich kann nur aus einem Gefühl heraus annehmen, dass (1) richtig und (2) falsch ist, kann das aber nicht durch handfeste Grammatikregeln untermauern. Gibt es Regeln, die meinem Empfinden entsprechen?

Comment: Bei mir ist es umgekehrt, Satz 2 scheint mir richtig und bei Satz 1 fehlt mir ein _nur so_, wie in _Er sah nur so aus, als ob ..._ Doch mit _nur so_ wäre der Satz dann definitiv irreal.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachgefühl hast Du Recht: ich würde immer die Konstruktion mit "als ob... Nickerchen..." verwenden. Ich würde "etwas sieht so aus, dass..." vermutlich in keinem Zusammenhang verwenden. Auch wenn ich den Regen schon am Horizont sehe und er quasi sicher ist, sage ich "es sieht so aus als ob es gleich regnen wird"

Comment: Genauer würde ich "etwas sieht aus" immer mit "als (ob)" formulieren. Und "denke", "sehe", ... mit "dass".

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne die offizielle Grammatikregel dazu nicht, aber der Konjunktiv drückt nicht nur frei erfundene Dinge aus, sondern auch ungewisse.

Wenn Scholten also ausdrücken will, dass der Kommissar sooo müde aussah, dass man es gar nicht anders interpretieren könnte, finde ich das Konstrukt „sieht aus, dass“ angemessen, wenn auch ungewöhnlich. Aber ich könnte mich gut dran gewöhnen.

Wenn es jedoch Spielraum ob der Müdigkeit des Kommissars gibt, finde ich „sieht aus, als ob“ angemessen.

Die ähnlich aussehende Formulierung „Es sieht so aus, dass er nicht mehr kommt“ (wenn jemand zu einem Termin nicht erscheint) kommt mir geläufig vor und könnte bei der Konstruktion von Satz (2) beteiligt gewesen sein.

Answer (score 3):

Zu Deinen Fragen:

1. Du hast recht. Der Hauptsatz lautet "Der Kommissar sieht aus." Wie genau sieht er aus? Die Antwort auf diese Frage ist eine Meinungsäußerung des Sprechenden ("als ob er ein Nickerchen vertragen könnte") und deshalb zurecht im Konjunktiv. Mag sein, daß der Sprechende recht hat, mag sein - jedenfalls gesteht er das zu - daß er sich irrt.

Die Konstruktion mit "dass" ist bestenfalls als Umgangssprache erklärbar, tatsächlich aber einfach falsch.

2. ja: "als" als Relation drückt einen Vergleich aus: "Ich bin größer als du". In Deinem Beispiel findet dieser Vergleich zwischen dem Aussehen und der Vermutung des Sprechers, worauf das zurückzuführen sei (nämlich dem Schlafbedürfnis), statt. "Als ob" bedeutet hier, daß wir eben keine Aussage über das Schlafbedürfnis per se amchen, sondern lediglich über den Anschein, den das Aussehen des Kommissars macht. Vielleicht wirkt es ja nur so, als ob? Sicher jedenfalls wirkt es nicht, dass.

@Roland Illig:
Das letzte sollte auch Deinen 2. Absatz beantworten: egal, wie sicher die Interpretation des Sprechers auch ist, sie ist genau das: eine Interpretation. Der Sprecher jedenfalls weiß nicht (und kann auch gar nicht wissen), ob der Kommissar wirklich müde/schläfrig ist oder nicht.

Dein Beispiel "Es sieht so aus, dass er nicht mehr kommt." kommt Dir mit Recht geläufig vor: es ist Umgangssprache. Das heißt aber nicht, *dass* es richtig ist - auch wenn es so wirkt, *als ob* es richtig wäre.

Tatsächlich müßte es - im Schriftdeutsch - richtig lauten: "es sieht so aus, als ob er nicht käme." Auch hier wird ein impliziter Vergleich aufgemacht, nämlich zwischen dem Anschein, den die Situation erweckt und der imaginierten Tatsache ("kommt tatsächlich nicht"/"kommt doch noch").

Wäre "es sieht so aus, dass er nicht mehr kommt" richtig, dann wäre das nicht-mehr-kommen eine Folge des so-Aussehens: "Ich schlage die Tür zu, dass es knallt."